# Catch value of Spinner JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

I'm trying to get value of Spinner(JavaFX). But return null.

Source:

```
    public class FXMLTeste implements Initializable {
        @FXML 
            private Spinner uni;

        @Override
        public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {       
            uni.setEditable(true);
        }  
        @FXML
        public void actionButton(){
            System.out.println(uni.getValue()); // return NULL
        }
}
```

#### fxml

```xml
<Spinner fx:id="uni" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="342.0"></Spinner>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the [`valueFactory`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Spinner.html#valueFactoryProperty) for the spinner to allow the `Spinner`'s value to become non-`null`. This can be done by directly assigning the property:

```xml
<Spinner fx:id="uni" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="342.0">
    <valueFactory>
        <!-- add factory instance creation here -->
    </valueFactory>
</Spinner>
```

by using the appropriate constructor

```xml
<Spinner fx:id="uni" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="342.0" min="1" max="10" initialValue="4" />
```

or by "manually" doing it in the `initialize` method:

```
SpinnerValueFactory valueFactory = ...
uni.setValueFactory(valueFactory);
```

Also you should specify the type parameter for the `Spinner`, even if it's a wildcard (`Spinner<?>`), see [What is a raw type and why shouldn't we use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it)

Making an educated guess, you may be looking for something like this:

```xml
<fx:define>
    <FXCollections fx:factory="observableArrayList" fx:id="unis" /> 
</fx:define>
<Spinner fx:id="uni" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="342.0" items="$unis" />
```

Controller

```
@FXML
private Spinner<String> uni;

@FXML
private ObservableList<String> unis;

@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
    unis.add("Oxford");
    unis.add("Harvard");
}
```